# How to a get a view of fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I am using `Fragment` in my android application. I need to get the view which I can get using.

```
mNoteEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);
```

This `mNoteEditText` is require to access in `onBackPressed` so every view reference I need to make them static variable because of `Fragment` class is static. I know to make every view to static variable is not good approach. How this I can make such that I dont need to make any static variable of the view.

```
public class NotesActivity extends Activity {

    private int bookId;
    private int chapterId;

    private static EditText mNoteEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);

        // get data from intent that sent from home activity
        bookId = getIntent().getIntExtra("book_id", -1);
        chapterId = getIntent().getIntExtra("book_id", -1);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new NoteFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A note fragment containing a note layout.
     */
    public static class NoteFragment extends Fragment {

        public NoteFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes,
                    container, false);
            mNoteEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        // get database instance
        MySQLiteOpenHelper db = MySQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance(this);

        Notes note = new Notes();
        note.setBookId(bookId);
        note.setChapterId(chapterId);
        note.setNote(mNoteEditText.getText().toString());

    }

}
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Fragment` has a Method called `getView()`. With it you can get the `View` of the `Fragment` as long as it is attached to an `Activity`.

```
View view = fragment.getView();
```

But if you are looking for a `View` inside the `Fragment` you can also just get it with `findViewById()` from the `Activity`. Again the `Fragment` has to be attached to the `Activity` for this to work.

**BUT** you should not do that. Nothing outside the `Fragment` should have anything to do with something inside the `Fragment`. Write public methods in the `Fragment` to interact with it. Try something like this:

```
public static class NoteFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText noteEditText;

    public NoteFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

        this.noteEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);

        return rootView;
    }

    // I added the following 3 methods to interact with the Fragment

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        final String text = this.noteEditText.getText().toString();
        return text.isEmpty();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.noteEditText.getText().toString();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.noteEditText.setText(text);
    }
}
```

And now in your `Activity` you can do this:

```
public class NotesActivity extends Activity {

    private int bookId;
    private int chapterId;

    private NoteFragment noteFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);

        // get data from intent that sent from home activity
        bookId = getIntent().getIntExtra("book_id", -1);
        chapterId = getIntent().getIntExtra("book_id", -1);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            this.noteFragment = new NoteFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, this.noteFragment).commit();
        }

        // Now you can interact with the Fragment
        this.noteFragment.setText("some text");

        ...

        if(!this.noteFragment.isEmpty()) {
            String note = this.noteFragment.getText();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you meant of this "Write public methods in the Fragment to interact with it." Please help